WSAEACCES error returned after Windows update
Last year, I finally migrated my development environment from Win10x64 to Win11x64.  The old Win10 computer has been powered off, except for the rare times I needed to look for an old file on it.  The software I work on was running fine when I moved from W10 to W11.  Yesterday, I powered it up to use it as a second host in some testing and it wanted to apply a bunch of updates.
Once it was finished and had rebooted a couple times, I tried to start my software and, to my surprise, all attempts to bind() a TCP socket to a local (IPv4) address/port are failing with WSAEACCES.  Since these programs have been working fine for, quite literally, YEARS on this very machine, I am at a loss as to how I should proceed in correcting the problem.
Our applications use a couple dozen ports starting at 0x4000, which was unassigned back when they were created.  I'm not bothering to post code because, since the code has worked correctly, and remained unchanged for several YEARS, I am 100% certain that the issue is external to our software -- other than, perhaps, our port selection.
I have tried turning off all anti-virus and firewall type security, but the error still occurs.  I have tried using only an internal LOOPBACK address (on the Microsoft KM-TEST loopback adapter) and also using an address on the physical adapter, with the same results.
This feels very much like an overzealous security update preventing anything from binding a TCP socket to an address/port.  Interestingly, the two places where the code binds a UDP address, there is no error, so this is TCP-specific.
Thanks to anyone who reads this far!  Even more thanks to anyone who can offer suggestions as to how I can correct or at least better diagnose what has changed that has broken my old code that once worked perfectly (and is currently still working perfectly on Windows 11, as well as on Windows 10 and Windows 7 at several customer sites!)
Oh, all our code is plain, native C (not C++, MFC, .NET or anything like that) and has not been changed (on the Win 10 machine) since it had last been run without error back in Dec 2023.

Found out that one of the updates reserved a bunch of ports that were previously in the dynamic port range.  If you have this problem, start an admin command prompt and run:
netsh int ipv4 show excludedportrange tcp

to see if your ports are listed.  If they are, these a version of these commands (with the port numbers and counts adjusted for your situation) will probably help:
net stop winnat
netsh int ipv4 set dynamic tcp start=49152 num=16384
netsh int ipv6 set dynamic tcp start=49152 num=16384
net start winnat

Beware though... after a reboot, Microsoft may have taken some ports back, so you should boot after doing this to ensure that your ports are still available.  If not, you may need to choose new ports to avoid MS interference.
EDIT:  I didn't list the ports that are being reserved because they seem to vary by system.  On mine there were several blocks of ports in the 16000s that were being reserved and since (back in 1993) we had elected to use 0x4000 (16384) as our base port, the reservations were breaking our programs.  For me, because the port reservations affecting us kept returning on reboot, we changed our base port to from 16384 to 21500.  Now we need to update all of the documentation, firewall settings, etc.  Thanks, Microsoft!

Your answer would even be better if it would mention the default excluded port range you encountered after the Windows updates, because at the moment neither question nor answer mentions details on the used ports, thus for other users it is very difficult to understand if they face the same problem.
